# AWS Api-Gateway CORS issue on status 400

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway

This is driving me totally crazy

Im trying to call a api-gateway rest service from an angular app that i have restricted from API-GATEWAY with IAM access. So i need to call with IAM authentication. Im using temporary IAM credentials that i have already obtained

My call to the service fails saying there is no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. When i try and call my service from postman i dont see the required header on the response. On my postman call I get a 403 status back since my authentication actually failed, but i still expected the header. If i remove the IAM authentication on the method it works, i get back the response string and the header im looking for.

What am i missing here? Surely even if my authentication failed i must still get back that header so that i can actually see the message that says your authentication failed.

Any help will be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: The newest thing ive tried was to create a bridging api-gateway service without authentication to be between my call and the authenticated service. The negative scenario works, if my authentication fails i get the cors header back, but my positive scenario doesnt. I get an error: _"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details"_

Answer (score 1):

From [this link on the AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=721190&#721190) it appears that there is an open issue related to exactly what im experiencing here... Not sure if what im looking for is currently possible

Comment: Just noting that this issue has been corrected via a new feature in API Gateway: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/customize-gateway-responses.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you allow your Cognito role to access to the API endpoints?

You have to use a policy similar to this one for the Cognito role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "execute-api:invoke"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:execute-api:<API_REGION>:<ACCOUNT_ID>:<API_ID>/*"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

If you use IAM authentication for your endpoint and if you do not allow the Cognito role to access to your API, API Gateway will generate a 403 response. **This response is not defined by your API definition** because the request is refused by API Gateway before it could get to the point of been processed by your API. **That is why your CORS configuration will not apply**.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you do **not** have AWS_IAM authentication enabled on your OPTIONS method, otherwise the browser will not be able to make the pre-flight request and your request will fail. You should still have AWS_IAM enabled on your other methods.

Comment: Thanks i checked but thats not it. I can actually do a OPTIONS call and i get back these headers, but as soon as I  call my POST method it doesnt come back `Access-Control-Allow-Headers →Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods →POST,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*`

Comment: This does seem to be related to failing my authentication. To test I entered my admin IAM key details into postman and made the request, and i correctly got back the header. When i change a digit to fail the authentication i dont. I obviously still need it, because the way things are now I cant see the correct errors because all i see is the CORS failure.

Comment: This is a current limitation with CORS support. We are currently tracking an item in our backlog to improve this. As of now, if the call does not authenticate you will see a CORS error rather than an authentication error.